# How to embed a video in beamer and reproduce it by using Okular?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, ubuntu, okular

A step by step tutorial will be appreciated!

Comment: For Okular, I would try `\usepackage{multimedia}`. See `texdoc beamer`.

Answer (score 2):

Run `texdoc media9` which opens the documentation of the package `media9`. It has examples for videos and 3d images.

Comment: Unfortunately, video and 3d won't be rendered in Okular; `media9` is (still) A-Reader only :(

Comment: So, what reader has the ability of playing videos in Ubuntu for instance?

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an easy solution to embed a video in a beamer presentation. Previously, it is needed to decompose the movie into its frames. I did it by using ffmpeg. For the new distributions of Ubuntu (I use the 14.04 release) one should download and build the source code as ffmpeg was removed from the official repository.

The command to extract the frames from a movie is:

```
ffmpeg -i inputMovie.mov outputFrame_%d.jpeg
```

It will include N frames of name *outputFrame_1* to *outputFrame_N*.
Suppose for this example N=42.

After that, add the next package to the latex preamble (the options can be changes as needed)

```
\usepackage[loop,controls,buttonsize=0.24cm,buttonbg=0.8,autoplay]{animate}
```

And include the next lines in one beamer slide. For instance,

```
\begin{frame}{Slide with movie}
\begin{figure}
\animategraphics[loop,width=.7\linewidth,every=1]{8}{outputFrame_}{1}{42}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
```

It works like a charm. Unfortunately, Okular does not reproduce the video and by the moment I read my file with acroread. It will be appreciated if anyone knows any other pdf reader able to play embedded videos.

Hope this helps!